# Capistrano 3 execute within a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, composer-php, capistrano3

I'm trying to write a task for Capistrano 3 that involves executing 'composer install' within the directory of the current release. It looks something like this:

```
namespace :composer do
  desc 'Install dependencies with Composer'
  task :install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute "#{fetch(:composer_command)} install"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`composer_command` is set in the staging and production files - in my particular case to `php /home/user/composer.phar`

For some reason this command does not actually run in the current release directory, but instead runs in the parent directory (containing current, shared, releases, etc)

I delved into this a bit further and found that when I ran a single word command, like:

```
within release_path do
    execute "pwd"
end
```

It works just fine, and runs the command in the current release directory. **But...** when I run a command with spaces, like:

```
within release_path do
    execute "pwd && ls"
end
```

It runs in the parent directory, and not the directory set by the `within` block.

Can someone shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Smells like a Cap 3 bug.

I suggest just guaranteeing you are where you want to be from the shell perspective:

```
execute "cd '#{release_path}'; #{fetch(:composer_command)} install"
```

Comment: I raised an issue - https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/719

Turns out that it's a constraint with SSHKit. So I'll go with your solution - the old capistrano 2 way, as it were.

Comment: It's explained [in the docs](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/tasks/). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32499307/52499).

Answer (score 11):

You can retain all the niceties of `within()`, `with()`, `default_env`, etc, while still keeping the natural string syntax:

```
within release_path do
  execute *%w[ pip install -r requirements.txt ]
end
```

Answer (score 7):

A couple of tips:

1) Capistrano uses [SSHKit](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit) for a lot of things, among which command execution. In order to simplify using Composer you could configure the command map (in `deploy.rb` or `production.rb`, etc), here are 2 examples:

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "#{shared_path.join('composer.phar')}"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = '/usr/bin/env composer.phar'
```

Next you can execute it like so:

```
execute :composer, :install
```

2) From a security perspective it's wise to disable the php setting `allow_url_fopen`, but unfortunately Composer needs it enabled to function. You can use this trick to leave it disabled globally:

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "/usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On #{shared_path.join('composer.phar')}"
```

Check out [iniscan](https://github.com/psecio/iniscan) for more security advise on php settings.

3) Composer has an option `-d, --working-dir`, which you can point to the directory containing the `composer.json` file in order to run Composer from any other directory. This should solve your problem:

```
execute :composer, '-d', release_path, :install
```

4) You may want to take a look at the [capistrano-composer](https://github.com/capistrano/composer) project :)

Comment: Don't know if it's due to updates to Capistrano, or my specific build case, but what I had to do was slightly modify your second example to:
`SSHKit.config.command_map[:composer] = "/[direct full path to]/composer.phar"` inside my deploy.rb. After that, adding `execute :composer, "install" within my .rake file worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, your use of the `within` function is *almost* correct. You have supplied it an entire string as a command, but the doc points out that this results in unreliable behaviour (which I have experienced myself).

Let the first argument to `execute` be a symbol instead of a string (which contains whitespace):

```
within release_path do
    execute fetch(:composer_command).to_sym, "install"
    execute :pwd
    execute :ls
end
```

Answer (score 4):

just for reference here is the [Capistrano Doc](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/tasks/) explaining why `within {}` does not work with arguments with whitespace. I hope this helps.