# Capistrano task start/restart pm2 How to pass the --env variable

Tags: node.js, capistrano, pm2

How can I pass the --env variable "staging or production" in the execute statement my Capistrano tasks ?

```
  def restart_app
    within current_path do
      execute :pm2, :restart, fetch(:app_command)
    end
  end

  def start_app
    within current_path do
      execute :pm2, :stop, fetch(:app_command)
    end
  end
```

currently once started , process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined

Comment: got a clue reading the following post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452983/capistrano-3-execute-within-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

I am using the within current path and I should change the execute command to *"retain all the niceties of within(), with(), default_env, etc, while still keeping the natural string syntax:"*

within current_path do
      execute *%w[ pm2 restart hello.js --env staging ]
  end